# jqplot stacked bar chart zoom colors lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I've implemented a stacked bar chart with a DateTime as the X axis and would like to enable zooming on it.  The original graph looks like this:
[image: original image]

When I attempt to zoom in (this time around the purple line) it looks like this:
[image: zoom attempt]

It appears that the actual zooming is working just fine but the arrangements of the bars are being lost.

How can I keep the different bars and still zoom in on a date range?

Code:

```
var plot2 = '';
var full_canvas_id = 'full-canvas';
var plot_options = {
    cursor:{ 
    show: true,
    zoom:true, 
},
    seriesColors: [ "#fffdf6","#c5b47f", "#579575", "#EAA228"],
    stackSeries: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        shadowAngle: 135,
        rendererOptions: {
        barMargin: '65',
        barDirection: 'horizontal',
    },
    pointLabels: {show: false}
}, axes: {
    yaxis: {
        pad:1.05,
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks:["Machine 521","Machine 358","Machine 415","Machine 1350","Machine 265","Machine 1126"]       
    }, xaxis: {
        min:'2012-05-01 0:00',
        max:'2012-06-15 17:50',
        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions:{
            formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d, %y'
        }
    }
}, legend: {
    labels:  ['Not Scheduled','Completed','Material','No Material'],
    show: true,
    location: 'e',
    placement: 'outside'
}, canvasOverlay: {
    show: true,
    objects: [
        {verticalLine: {
            name: 'Current Time',
            x: 1338674277000,
            lineWidth: 1,
            color: 'rgb(100, 55, 124)',
            shadow: false,
            lineCap: 'butt',
            xOffset: 0
        }}
        ]
    }         
};

var tooltip_request;

function build_tooltip(part_lot_id, column, start_date, end_date) {
    if(column == 0) $('div.tooltip').hide();
    tooltip_request = $.getJSON('/?fn=material_schedule&a=get_graph_tooltip&pli='+part_lot_id+'&col='+column,function(j) {
    $('div.tooltip div.wrapper').html(j.title + '<br>Start:' + make_full_date(start_date) + '<br>End:' + make_full_date(end_date) + '<br>' + j.html);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
plot2 = $.jqplot(full_canvas_id, [[["2012-05-01 0:00",1,"1"],["2012-05-07 0:00",2,"1"],["2012-05-01 0:00",3,"3"],["2012-05-06 0:00",4,"3"],["2012-05-08 0:00",5,"3"],["2012-06-05 0:00",6,"4"]],[["2012-06-02 15:57",1,"1"],["2012-06-02 15:57",2,"1"],["2012-06-02 15:57",3,"3"],["2012-06-02 15:57",4,"3"],["2012-06-02 15:57",5,"3"],["2012-06-05 0:00",6,"4"]],[["2012-06-06 16:17",1,"1"],["2012-06-06 16:17",2,"1"],["2012-06-04 18:54",3,"3"],["2012-06-04 18:54",4,"3"],["2012-06-04 18:54",5,"3"],["2012-06-06 16:17",6,"4"]],[["2012-06-07 3:20",1,"1"],["2012-06-07 3:20",2,"1"],["2012-06-13 17:50",3,"3"],["2012-06-13 17:50",4,"3"],["2012-06-13 17:50",5,"3"],["2012-06-08 17:39",6,"4"]]], plot_options);
$('#'+full_canvas_id).bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data ) {
    if($('div.tooltip').length == 0) {
        $('body').append($('<div></div>').addClass('tooltip'));
        $('div.tooltip').append($('<div></div>').addClass('wrapper'));
    }
    clearTimeout($('div.tooltip').data('timeout'));
    console.log(plot2);
    var t_x = (plot2.axes.xaxis.u2p(data[0])*1) + ($('#'+full_canvas_id).offset().left * 1);
    var t_y = (plot2.axes.yaxis.u2p(data[1])*1) + ($('#'+full_canvas_id).offset().top * 1);
    $('div.tooltip').css({'left' : t_x + 'px','top' : t_y + 'px'}).stop(true,true).show();

    if(seriesIndex == 0) var start_date = plot2.axes.xaxis.min;
    else var start_date = plot2.series[seriesIndex-1].data[pointIndex][0];
    build_tooltip(plot2.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex][2], seriesIndex, start_date, plot2.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex][0]);
    clearTimeout($('div.tooltip').data('timeout'));
    $('div.tooltip, div.tooltip .wrapper').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').mouseenter(function() {
        clearTimeout($('div.tooltip').data('timeout'));
        $(this).stop(true,true).show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
            var tt = this;
            clearTimeout($('div.tooltip').data('timeout'));
            $('div.tooltip').data('timeout',setTimeout(function() {
                $(tt).hide();
                },'200'));
            });
        });
        $('#'+full_canvas_id).bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight', function (ev,seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
        clearTimeout($('div.tooltip').data('timeout'));
        $('div.tooltip').data('timeout',setTimeout(function() {
            $('div.tooltip').stop(true,true).hide();
        },'200'));
    });
});


function make_full_date(timestamp) {
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var end_date = new Date(timestamp);
    var hour = end_date.getHours();
    var min = end_date.getMinutes();
    if(min < 10) min = '0' + min;
    return months[end_date.getMonth()] + ' ' + end_date.getDate() + ', ' + end_date.getFullYear() + '@' + hour + ':' + min;
}
```

Comment: Please make a http://jsfiddle.net presenting your problem rather than pasting the code. BTW does it occur in all browsers?

Comment: I made a code sample based on your code, http://jsfiddle.net/aQX8F/19/ hope someone knowing the answer finds it useful.

Comment: Here goes a sample showing that zoom works fine without `DateAxisRenderer` http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/aQX8F/16/